# spawning multiple Background processes

Tags: process, background-process

I have a file which has `2,000,000` lines in it. I am running some commands for each line. I was trying to achieve some parallelism using `GNU-parallel` and `swift` as discussed [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114962/parallel-execution-of-bash-script). However, I got an interesting idea from one of my friends.

He was suggesting to spawn multiple processes in the server since the server is pretty powerful. I was thinking if I use an index for each line of file, I could spawn multiple processes based on the `totallines mod number_of_processes`.

For example, **if line_numbers are 1,11 and 21, it will be sent to first process and if line numbers are 2,12 and 22 it will be sent to second process so on.**

To achieve the above, I was going through background processes in shell scripting. In most of the tutorials/links, they are appending an `&` to the command and telling that a background process will be spawned by the computer. I am finding it little difficult to understand this concept.

Answer (score 2):

How does your idea differ from GNU Parallel's --pipe --round-robin?

```
seq 100 | parallel --pipe --round-robin -j10 -N 1 'echo Start;cat'
```

Doing it line by line is somewhat inefficient for GNU Parallel. Doing it block by block is more efficient:

```
seq 1000000 | parallel --pipe --round-robin -j10 'echo Start;cat'
```

Adjust --block to suit your needs.

Comment: I have installed gnu-parallel in my system and am running my script by typing "./script_name.sh | parallel --pipe --round-robin -j10 'cat' > output2. However, I am not able to see the output in my output2 file.

Comment: Do the examples above work?

Comment: Yeah, it is working.