# Background execution in parallel

Tags: background-process, parallelism

I have a program `./pgm` taking some arguments (say `-a file1 -b val`), which requires 2 seconds to execute. I would like to use all the processors on my machine to run this program on all the input files in parallel (about 1000). What I do now, is put all the commands

```
./pgm -a file1 -b 12 > out1.txt &
./pgm -a file2 -b 14 > out2.txt &
./pgm -a file3 -b 16 > out3.txt &
./pgm -a file4 -b 18 > out4.txt &
...
```

in a file, and execute this file. I thought this would use all the available processors, but the number of parallel execution is very limited.

How can I achieve this? Note that `parallel` command is not an option.

Comment: What machine is this? Is this a normal PC or some kind of server with multiple nodes?

Comment: Maybe pgm is i/o bound then extra CPU doesn't help. `vmstat 1 1` in a second terminal whilst other is running for a few secconds would give you a rough idea.

Comment: Which parallel are you referring to [GNU parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) or the one from [moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/)? Or both?

Comment: Can you based on http://oletange.blogspot.dk/2013/04/why-not-install-gnu-parallel.html elaborate why GNU Parallel is not an option?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. @OleTange: I tried but the installation failed, and I am not root.

Comment: @XTian: you are right, there are IO blockings. `vmstat` gives `bo=1`. Does this explains why when I run `xargs`with `-P8` there is only one process running sometime?

Comment: `vmstat 1 1` is not useful because it gives you the average statistics since the system booted. `vmstat 3` (or `iostat -z 3`) to get running statistics every 3 seconds. Did you add the `-n1` to `xargs`. You don't have to install `parallel` system-wide to use it, you can put it somewhere in your home directory.

Comment: @wwjoze Can you elaborate how '(wget pi.dk/3 -qO - ||  curl pi.dk/3/) | bash' fails? What error do you get?

Answer (score 5):

With GNU `xargs`:

```
seq 1000 | xargs -P4 -n1  sh -c 'exec ./pgm -a "file$1" -b 12 > "out.$1"' sh &
```

Would run up to 4 `./pgm`s in parallel.

Otherwise, with `pdksh`/`mksh`/`oksh`:

```
trap : CHLD
n=0
for f in file*; do
  jobs=$(jobs | wc -l)
  if (($jobs < 4)); then
    ./pgm "$f" > out.$((++n)) &
  else
    wait
  fi
done
trap - CHLD
wait
```

the details of signal handling vary from one shell to the next. That trick works in `pdksh` and its derivatives but not in any other shell I tried. You need a shell where one can trap SIGCHLD (excludes `bash`), where the SIGCHLD handler is executed straight away (not blocked during a `wait`) (excludes `ash`, [`yash`](http://yash.sourceforge.jp/index.html.en)), where the SIGCHLD handling interrupts the `wait` (excludes `ksh93` and `zsh`).

In shells other than `bash`, you could also look at approaches where jobs are started in the SIGCHLD handler.

Comment: Thanks for the command line using `xargs`. But it seems my process uses to much IO to be fully parallelized.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar kind of issue. Since you had specified `parallel` is not an option, you might need to look into `swift` as discussed in the answer of [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114962/parallel-execution-of-bash-script) question.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Sure. I will keep this in mind before posting any future answers. Thanks for pointing it out.