# Prevent GNU parallel from splitting quoted arguments

Tags: command-line, quoting, gnu-parallel

I'm trying to use [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) to run a comman mutliple times with a combination of constant and varying arguments. But for some reason the constant arguments are split on white-space even though I've quoted them when passing them to `parallel`.

In this example, the constant argument `'a b'` should be passed to `debug-call` as a single argument instead of two:

```
$ parallel debug-call 'a b' {} ::: {1..2}
[0] = '[...]/debug-call'
[1] = 'a'
[2] = 'b'
[3] = '1'
[0] = '[...]/debug-call'
[1] = 'a'
[2] = 'b'
[3] = '2'
```

`debug-call` is a [simple script](https://gist.github.com/Feuermurmel/1964dea9fc6280cf4911494d4261b2f5) which prints each argument it has been passed in `argv`. Instead I would expect to see this output:

```
[0] = '[...]/debug-call'
[1] = 'a b'
[2] = '1'
[0] = '[...]/debug-call'
[1] = 'a b'
[2] = '2'
```

Is this a bug or is there a option to prevent GNU Parallel from splitting command line arguments before passing them on to the command?

Comment: Use `parallel` with `-q`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`parallel` runs a shell (which exact one depending on the context in which it is called, generally, when called from a shell, it's that same shell) to parse the concatenation of the arguments.

So:

```
parallel debug-call 'a b' {} ::: 'a b' c
```

is the same as

```
parallel 'debug-call a b {}' ::: 'a b' c
```

`parallel` will call:

```
your-shell -c 'debug-call a b <something>'
```

Where `<something>` is the arguments (hopefully) properly quoted for that shell. For instance, if that shell is `bash`, it will run

```
bash -c 'debug-call a b a\ b'
```

Here, you want:

```
parallel 'debug-call "a b" {}' ::: 'a b' c
```

Or

```
parallel -q debug-call 'a b' {} ::: 'a b' c
```

Where `parallel` will quote the arguments (in the correct (hopefully) syntax for the shell) before concatenating.

To avoid calling a shell in the first place, you could use GNU `xargs` instead:

```
xargs -n1 -r0 -P4 -a <(printf '%s\0' 'a b' c) debug-call 'a b'
```

That won't invoke a shell (nor any of the many commands ran by `parallel` upon initialisation), but you won't benefit from any of the extra features of `parallel`, like output reordering with `-k`.

You may find other approaches at [Background execution in parallel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/115727)

Comment: Thank you for you answer. `-q` seems to work. Is it possible to prevent my shell from getting called at all? I.e. having `parallel` pass the arguments directly to `execvp(3)` or similar?

Comment: @Feuermurmel, see discussion at https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-parallel/2015-05/msg00005.html

Comment: It seems that GNU Parallel is not the right tool for what I want to do. I will have another look at `xargs`. I remember that being even worse, but maybe I am mistaken.

Comment: @Feuermurmel, see edit for GNU `xargs` example