# Starting GNU Parallel in background?

Tags: linux, background-process, gnu-parallel

Is it possible to start GNU Parallel in the background, or somehow, send it to the background?

I want to do this so that I can use two commands that run `parallel` at the same time.

And why don't I execute everything in one parallel command? Two reasons:

1. parallel slows down after a while,
2. because I want to separate it so I can stop execution of one group without stopping everything

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you'd want to do this? This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I have a script that downloads files with wget, I want to download as fast as possible. This is what I want.

Comment: Understand, but you're limited by your network connection so running many `wget`'s in parallel will not work, all you'll be doing is dividing up the fixed amount of bandwidth over many vs. 1 or 2. Rather then bother with `parallel` here you should just run `wget` backgrounded directly. Running 1-3 will likely saturate your network connection.

Comment: As an a for example, see this SO Q&A titled: [multiple wget -r a site simultaneously?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745799/multiple-wget-r-a-site-simultaneously)

Comment: A tool such as `axel` might be a better fit here too if you're downloading a file, but want to download it over multiple connections.

Comment: Also, depending on the structure of the URLs you're downloading from, these approaches might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577615/parallel-wget-in-bash

Comment: I would like to run wget separate, the thing is that the bash script does a number of operations to determine the correct URL to send to ```wget```. I wish I could write some sort of implementation in C++ to do all the operations and have the program send the URLs to a fixed number of ```wget```s. I've been reading a bit on Swift to do this but I'm no master programmer unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to run parallel in background. Recently, I was working on similar scripts which I needed to execute in parallel and I got the suggestions in [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114962/parallel-execution-of-bash-script) answer. If you go to the link [specified](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html) as part of my answer, I see the below answer.

GNU Parallel can work as a counting semaphore. This is slower and less efficient than its normal mode.

An alias for `parallel --semaphore` is `sem`. The default is to allow only one program to run at a time (technically called a mutex). The program is started in the background. Use `--wait` for all 'sem's to finish:

```
sem 'sleep 1; echo The first finished' &&
    echo The first is now running in the background &&
    sem 'sleep 1; echo The second finished' &&
    echo The second is now running in the background
  sem --wait
```

If you see the examples in the link that I had provided, you can definitely find what you are looking for.

Comment: My goal with starting ```parallel``` in background is to be able to execute even more things at the same time.

Comment: I understand it :) I would also go through Amdahl's law to understand how much parallelism can be effectively achieved.

Answer (score 1):

I often run things several different groups of task in parallel:

```
parallel do_stuff ::: x y z
```

I then realize that `do_stuff` takes a long time to run, and that I want my terminal back, so I press CTRL-Z and type:

```
bg
```

to put the job in the background.

Then I might start another job:

```
parallel do_other_stuff ::: foo bar baz
```

This new job will run in parallel with `do_stuff`.