# How to call a service URL from bash shell script in parallel?

Tags: bash, shell-script, download, multithreading

I have a service which I am calling from another application. Below is my service URL which I am calling -

```
http://www.betaservice.domain.host.com/web/hasChanged?ver=0
```

I need to do some load test on my above service URL in multithreaded way instead of calling sequentially one by one.

Is there any way from bash shell script, I can put a load on my above service URL by calling it in multithreaded way? I can have 60-70 threads calling above URL in parallel very fast if possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I wouldn't call it multithreading as such but you could simply launch 70 jobs in the background:

```
for i in {1..70}; do 
   wget http://www.betaservice.domain.host.com/web/hasChanged?ver=0 2>/dev/null &
done
```

That will result in 70 `wget` processes running at once. You can also do something more sophisticated like this little script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

## The time (in minutes) the script will run for. Change 10
## to whatever you want.
end=$(date -d "10 minutes" +%s);

## Run until the desired time has passed.
while [ $(date +%s) -lt "$end" ]; do 
    ## Launch a new wget process if there are
    ## less than 70 running. This assumes there
    ## are no other active wget processes.
    if [ $(pgrep -c wget) -lt 70 ]; then
        wget http://www.betaservice.domain.host.com/web/hasChanged?ver=0 2>/dev/null &
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks. I got it now, so I can just increase the 70 value right? Is this possible to keep on doing this load test for 10-15 minutes consistently?

Comment: @user2809564 see updated answer.

Comment: sure, Thanks for the edit. When I ran above script, I got error as `pgrep: invalid option -- 'c'`. I am not sure why, can you think of what might be the reason?

Comment: @user2809564 you probably have a different `pgrep` implementation. Is this Linux? Which one? Anyway, you can just change that line to `if [ $(pgrep wget | wc -l) -lt 70 ]; then`

Answer (score 9):

Try ab, you get a nice statistic too:

```
ab -n 10000 -c 70 http://www.betaservice.domain.host.com/web/hasChanged?ver=0
```

This call will do 10000 requests with concurrency of 70 parallel queries.

Comment: how can I install apache bench in `Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.3`?

Comment: `yum install httpd-tools`, according to http://serverfault.com/a/363775/10989

Answer (score 6):

You could try installing GNU parallel. You could get some GNU parallel examples from [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html).

**Testing**

I installed `gnu-parallel` from source in my machine and I could get it to work.

You could install it from source from [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/). I have a redhat system and so I downloaded the fedora package and then ran the `.configure`, `make` and `make install` to get the `parallel` installed in my system.

Now, after the successful installation, I created a directory `checking` and ran the below command.

```
seq 10 | parallel -n0  wget http://www.betaservice.domain.host.com/web/hasChanged?ver=0
```

As expected the above command downloaded me 10 copies of the web page. You could set the number that you wish with `seq`.

For more information on how to run the same command in parallel, you could verify the examples provided by gnu-parallel from [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#EXAMPLE:-Transferring-of-files). From the example page,

> If you want to run the same command with the same arguments 10 times
>   in parallel you can do:
>
> seq 10 | parallel -n0 my_command my_args

**EDIT**

Now, to take advantage of the `parallel` execution, you could use the command as,

```
 seq 70 | parallel -j70 wget http://www.betaservice.domain.host.com/web/hasChanged?ver=0
```

The `-j` option is something that could specify the total jobs that can be executed in parallel based on the total CPU cores.

Comment: Thanks Ramesh. How many times it will call my service with this approach?

Comment: @user2809564, see the updates.

Comment: cool. Also is this possible to keep on doing this load test for 10-15 minutes consistently?

Comment: I think this example will provide more insights. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7627103/1742825

Comment: @user2809564, please refer to this question as well where I got the suggestion to use `GNU parallel`. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114962/parallel-execution-of-bash-script