# A linux "cp" command equivalent that does read/write threading and buffer sharing for increased throughput?

Tags: linux, cp, io

First, let me address your concerns.

I'm copying from one slow drive, to another (different) slow drive. Blocking for reads on one drive until I write to another leaves a lot of room for improvement.

I developed a small cpp/h file that does this for me. It improved speed in my use case by ~40%. https://github.com/pauldotknopf/AsyncStreamCopyCPP/blob/master/examples/main.cpp

I'd like to know if there is something equivalent, but as a command. Preferably one that is similar to how the "cp" command operates.

```bsh
# Use async read/write threads and shared/re-used buffers between the two.
cp /slowdrive1/file1.txt /slowdrive2/file2.txt
```

Comment: Did you flush the system buffers before testing the speed? `echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`

Comment: `// pretend this function takes a while!` - did you test without pretending?  The Linux kernel implements async readahead.

Comment: Relevant: [Multithreaded cp on linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/165256/86440).